# Mixed WaveMaker/Java project - how to do it?

Tags: version-control, code-generation, roundtrip, wavemaker

WaveMaker is a RAD tool that generates Java and Javascript code - so:

1. Which files should be checked in to version control, and which files
   should be ignored?
2. What happens if I want to customise the generated code? Will my customisations be silently overwritten?
3. Can customised code be round-tripped back into WaveMaker?
4. What about database changes made outside WaveMaker - can they be round-tripped?
5. If I make changes to generated code, will this change the answer to question 1?
6. Or, should direct customisation of generated code be avoided? If so, what should be done instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are answers to your questions:

Q1. Which files should be checked in to version control, and which files should be ignored?

A1. See the documentation on [Software Configuration Management](http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/wmdoc_6.4/Software+Configuration+Management) with WaveMaker, w
hich outlines which files should be checked-in.  All others can be ignored.

Q2. What happens if I want to customise the generated code? Will my customisations be silently overwritten?

A2. WaveMaker Studio executes the code within Studio so your changes are reflected during development and, of course, are executed in your running application.  You can further edit within WaveMaker as well.

Q3. Can customised code be round-tripped back into WaveMaker?

A3. Yes, most editors within WaveMaker have a "Refresh from Server" button so if you make changes outside of WaveMaker Studio you can force WaveMaker to re-read the file and load your most recent code.  If there is no "Refresh from Server" button you can always close the project and re-open, which will force WaveMaker to re-read your code.

Q4. What about database changes made outside WaveMaker - can they be round-tripped?

A4. See A3.

Q5. If I make changes to generated code, will this change the answer to question 1?
Or, should direct customisation of generated code be avoided? If so, what should be done instead?

A5. I would recommend against editing the widgets.js file that is created for each page in your application.  If you edit make sure you re-open the project after editing.